# Can not get all the data when crawling a website

Tags: java, web-crawler, html

I have been trying to crawl a website and get some data from it. The webpage which I want to crawl is this one: http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/everton-chelsea-4tRin4kn/
I am specifically interested in getting the numbers in the table in the middle of the page. I tried crawling it in the most basic way by just printing the html code and my idea was to then search the html for the numbers and save them in a file. The problem is that I can't find these numbers anywhere in the html. Even when I open it in a browser and click on show source code I still cant find them. This is the code which I am using.

```
  private static String getUrlSource(String url) throws IOException {
        URL yahoo = new URL(url);
        URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            a.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        return a.toString();
    }
```

Any advice on how I can get the data from the table would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. Run the JS that's on the page that loads the data, or
2. Look at the network requests the page makes and see if you can request the data directly.

Note that #2 may violate the site's TOS.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Chrome right click on the table and select 'inspect element', the numbers are in fact there in the html. To extract certain numbers from the page it is usually useful to use a library like Jsoup so that you can extract text based on the structure of the html page.

Comment: Not quite correct; inspecting elements inspects the *DOM*, not the HTML sent by the original request. The table contents are loaded dynamically, which means they're unavailable until the page's DOM-ready JS has fired and actually loaded up the table. JSoup won't help.

Comment: Does that mean that there is no way to somehow read them with java?